Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6E AX211 not Working on Core Ultra (Intel Corporation Meteor Lake PCH CNVi WiFi)
Problem Description:
I encountered an issue where the WiFi driver is not functioning correctly on a system with an Intel Corporation Meteor Lake PCH CNVi WiFi card.
Despite having the firmware-iwlwifi package installed, the system fails to load the necessary firmware files for the WiFi card, resulting in no WiFi connectivity.
System Information:

OS
root@DEB-NUC14RVS-ASUSNUC14ProPlus:~# cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="12"
VERSION="12 (bookworm)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bookworm
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"

root@DEB-NUC14RVS-ASUSNUC14ProPlu:~# cat /etc/debian_version
12.6

Kernel
root@DEB-NUC14RVS-ASUSNUC14ProPlus:~# uname -a
Linux DEB-NUC14RVS-ASUSNUC14ProPlus 6.9.7+bpo-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.9.7- 
1~bpo12+1 (2024-07-03) x86_64 GNU/Linux


Network Card Details:
root@DEB-NUC14RVS-ASUSNUC14ProPlus:~# lspci -q -nn | grep -i network
00:08.0 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation Meteor Lake-P Gaussian & Neural- 
Network Accelerator [8086:7e4c] (rev 20)
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Meteor Lake PCH CNVi WiFi 
[8086:7e40] (rev 20)



Steps Taken:

Installed WiFi Drivers:

     root@DEB-NUC14RVS-ASUSNUC14ProPlus:~# lspci -nnk | grep -A3 0280
     00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Meteor Lake PCH CNVi WiFi 
     [8086:7e40] (rev 20)
     DeviceName: Onboard - Ethernet
     Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6E AX211 160MHz [8086:0094]
     Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi


Verified Installation of firmware-iwlwifi:

   root@DEB-NUC14RVS-ASUSNUC14ProPlu:~# sudo apt install firmware-iwlwifi
   Reading package lists... Done
   Building dependency tree... Done
   Reading state information... Done
   firmware-iwlwifi is already the newest version (20230210-5).
   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 10 not upgraded.


Checked dmesg Logs for iwlwifi:

root@DEB-NUC14RVS-ASUSNUC14ProPlus:~# sudo dmesg | grep iwlwifi
[    2.939942] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    2.941591] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected crf-id 0x400410, cnv-id 0x1080800 wfpm id 0x80000020
[    2.941604] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: PCI dev 7e40/0094, rev=0x441, rfid=0x2010d000
[    2.941758] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-ma-b0-gf-a0-89.ucode (-2)
[    2.941770] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-ma-b0-gf-a0-89.ucode (-2)
[    2.941772] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ma-b0-gf-a0-89.ucode failed with error -2


[    2.942146] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-ma-b0-gf-a0-69.ucode (-2)
[    2.942147] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ma-b0-gf-a0-69.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.942155] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-ma-b0-gf-a0-68.ucode (-2)
[    2.942162] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-ma-b0-gf-a0-68.ucode (-2)
[    2.942163] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ma-b0-gf-a0-68.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.942173] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-ma-b0-gf-a0-67.ucode 
[    2.942317] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-ma-b0-gf-a0-59.ucode (-2)
[    2.942318] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ma-b0-gf-a0-59.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.942319] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: no suitable firmware found!
[    2.942324] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: minimum version required: iwlwifi-ma-b0-gf-a0-59
[    2.942327] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: maximum version supported: iwlwifi-ma-b0-gf-a0-89
[    2.942329] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: check git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git[/code]

Upon investigating the error, it was clear that the system couldn't find suitable firmware:
.942318] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ma-b0-gf-a0-59.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.942319] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: no suitable firmware found!
[    2.942324] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: minimum version required: iwlwifi-ma-b0-gf-a0-59
[    2.942327] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: maximum version supported: iwlwifi-ma-b0-gf-a0-89
[    2.942329] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: check git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.gi[/code]

However, the firmware module iwlwifi-ma-b0-gf-a0-59 was missing from the /lib/firmware/ directory:
root@DEB-NUC14RVS-ASUSNUC14ProPlus:/lib/firmware# ls | grep iwlwifi-ma-b0-gf-a0-59

root@DEB-NUC14RVS-ASUSNUC14ProPlus:/lib/firmware# ls
3com                                ctefx.bin                          iwlwifi-cc-a0-59.ucode         powervr
advansys                            ctspeq.bin                         iwlwifi-cc-a0-72.ucode         qca
agere_ap_fw.bin                     cxgb3                              iwlwifi-ma-b0-gf-a0-89.ucode   r128
agere_sta_fw.bin                    cxgb4                              iwlwifi-Qu-b0-hr-b0-50.ucode   r8a779x_usb3_v1.dlmem
airoha                              cypress                            iwlwifi-Qu-b0-hr-b0-59.ucode   r8a779x_usb3_v3.dlmem
amd                                 dabusb                             iwlwifi-Qu-b0-hr-b0-72.ucode   radeon
amdgpu                              dsp56k                             iwlwifi-Qu-b0-jf-b0-50.ucode   regulatory.db
amd-ucode                           dvb-fe-xc4000-1.4.1.fw             iwlwifi-Qu-b0-jf-b0-59.ucode   regulatory.db-debian
amphion                             dvb-fe-xc5000-1.6.114.fw           iwlwifi-Qu-b0-jf-b0-72.ucode   regulatory.db.p7s
ar3k                                dvb-fe-xc5000c-4.1.30.7.fw         iwlwifi-Qu-c0-hr-b0-50.ucode   regulatory.db.p7s-debian
ar5523.bin                          dvb-usb-dib0700-1.20.fw            iwlwifi-Qu-c0-hr-b0-59.ucode   regulatory.db.p7s-upstream
ar7010_1_1.fw                       dvb-usb-it9135-01.fw               iwlwifi-Qu-c0-hr-b0-72.ucode   regulatory.db-upstream
ar7010.fw                           dvb-usb-it9135-02.fw               iwlwifi-Qu-c0-jf-b0-50.ucode   rockchip
ar9271.fw                           dvb-usb-terratec-h5-drxk.fw        iwlwifi-Qu-c0-jf-b0-59.ucode   rp2.fw
arm                                 ene-ub6250                         iwlwifi-Qu-c0-jf-b0-72.ucode   RTL8192E
as102_data1_st.hex                  f2255usb.bin                       iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-50.ucode  rtl_bt
as102_data2_st.hex                  go7007                             iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-59.ucode  rtl_nic
ath10k                              htc_7010.fw                        iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-72.ucode  rtlwifi
ath11k                              htc_9271.fw                        iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-jf-b0-50.ucode  rtw88
ath3k-1.fw                          i915                               iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-jf-b0-59.ucode  rtw89
ath6k                               imx                                iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-jf-b0-72.ucode  s2250.fw
atmel_at76c502_3com.bin             intel                              iwlwifi-so-a0-gf4-a0-72.ucode  s2250_loader.fw
atmel_at76c502_3com-wpa.bin         intel-ucode                        iwlwifi-so-a0-gf4-a0.pnvm      sd8385.bin
atmel_at76c502.bin                  isci                               iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-72.ucode   sd8385_helper.bin
atmel_at76c502d.bin                 iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode               iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0.pnvm       sd8686.bin
atmel_at76c502d-wpa.bin             iwlwifi-100-5.ucode                iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-72.ucode   sd8686_helper.bin
atmel_at76c502e.bin                 iwlwifi-105-6.ucode                iwlwifi-so-a0-jf-b0-72.ucode   sd8688.bin
atmel_at76c502e-wpa.bin             iwlwifi-135-6.ucode                iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-59.ucode   sd8688_helper.bin
atmel_at76c502-wpa.bin              iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode               iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-66.ucode   tehuti
atmel_at76c503-i3861.bin            iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode               iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-72.ucode   ti
atmel_at76c503-i3863.bin            iwlwifi-3160-17.ucode              iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0.pnvm       ti-connectivity
atmel_at76c503-rfmd-0.90.2-140.bin  iwlwifi-3168-29.ucode              kaweth                         tigon
atmel_at76c503-rfmd-acc.bin         iwlwifi-3945-2.ucode               keyspan_pda                    ti-keystone
atmel_at76c503-rfmd.bin             iwlwifi-4965-2.ucode               lbtf_usb.bin                   ueagle-atm
atmel_at76c504_2958-wpa.bin         iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode               libertas                       usb8388.bin
atmel_at76c504a_2958-wpa.bin        iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode               libertas_cs.fw                 usbduxfast_firmware.bin
atmel_at76c504.bin                  iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode               libertas_cs_helper.fw          usbdux_firmware.bin
atmel_at76c504c-wpa.bin             iwlwifi-6000g2a-6.ucode            liquidio                       usbduxsigma_firmware.bin
atmel_at76c505a-rfmd2958.bin        iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode            lt9611uxc_fw.bin               v4l-cx231xx-avcore-01.fw
atmel_at76c505-rfmd2958.bin         iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode               matrox                         v4l-cx23418-apu.fw
atmel_at76c505-rfmd.bin             iwlwifi-7260-17.ucode              meson                          v4l-cx23418-cpu.fw
atmel_at76c506.bin                  iwlwifi-7265-17.ucode              microchip                      v4l-cx23418-dig.fw
atmel_at76c506-wpa.bin              iwlwifi-7265D-29.ucode             moxa                           v4l-cx23885-avcore-01.fw
av7110                              iwlwifi-8000C-36.ucode             mrvl                           v4l-cx25840.fw
bnx2                                iwlwifi-8265-36.ucode              mts_cdma.fw                    vntwusb.fw
bnx2x                               iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-34.ucode  mts_edge.fw                    wfx
brcm                                iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-38.ucode  mts_gsm.fw                     wil6210.brd
cadence                             iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode  mwl8k                          wil6210.fw
carl9170-1.fw                       iwlwifi-9260-th-b0-jf-b0-34.ucode  netronome                      xe
cavium                              iwlwifi-9260-th-b0-jf-b0-38.ucode  nvidia                         zd1211
cis                                 iwlwifi-9260-th-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode  nxp
cnm                                 iwlwifi-cc-a0-50.ucode             phanfw.bin


Attempted to resolve the issue by downloading iwlwifi-ma-b0-gf-a0-89.ucode and moving it to /lib/firmware/, but the problem persisted.
https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/
root@DEB-NUC14RVS-ASUSNUC14ProPlus:~# ls
iwlwifi-ma-b0-gf-a0-89.ucode  
root@DEB-NUC14RVS-ASUSNUC14ProPlus:~# mv iwlwifi-ma-b0-gf-a0-89.ucode /lib/firmware/

Initially, I attempted the following changes, which allowed WiFi configuration in the NetworkManager interface but didn't fully resolve the connectivity issue:

Modified NetworkManager Configuration:

cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=true

Previously, the [ifupdown] section had managed=false, which was changed to managed=true.

Created a Modprobe Configuration File: Created the file /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf with the following options:

options iwlwifi swcrypto=1 11n_disable=1

Status of all wireless devices:
sudo rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no

lists detailed information about network interfaces
root@DEB-NUC14RVS-S5ARYZ00X752FXH:~# inxi -Nn
Network:
  Device-1: Intel Meteor Lake PCH CNVi WiFi driver: N/A
  Device-2: Intel Ethernet I226-V driver: igc
  IF: eth0 state: up speed: 1000 Mbps duplex: full mac: 88:ae:dd:65:5b:f4
  IF-ID-1: br-24dc7019c851 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: unknown mac: 02:42:ca:c6:b2:ee
  IF-ID-2: br-606ef571aba0 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: unknown mac: 02:42:16:ea:b1:e4
  IF-ID-3: br-97f064bcae82 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: unknown mac: 02:42:b9:8d:4b:b2
  IF-ID-4: br-abc7ad78efc3 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: unknown mac: 02:42:de:6a:dd:d7
  IF-ID-5: docker0 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: unknown mac: 02:42:cd:da:7c:da
  IF-ID-6: veth07f4cbf state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full mac: aa:f6:d9:16:4c:c2
  IF-ID-7: veth09db74d state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full mac: 36:2f:65:a2:d2:f5
  IF-ID-8: veth1ae99be state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full mac: 0e:6d:c6:61:43:39
  IF-ID-9: veth234de15 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full mac: be:44:1d:60:7d:3c
  IF-ID-10: veth38475e2 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full mac: 7a:cf:b6:94:5e:5a
  IF-ID-11: veth4bbd97c state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full mac: 22:25:21:d6:b1:d3
  IF-ID-12: veth516d8f8 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full mac: 3a:ab:ef:16:2d:77
  IF-ID-13: veth655547a state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full mac: 92:1d:8c:ee:f9:26
  IF-ID-14: veth6c3c5b1 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full mac: 6e:35:b8:7f:03:e1
  IF-ID-15: veth78ea674 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full mac: 1e:55:b5:c7:51:dd
  IF-ID-16: veth9298646 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full mac: 4e:a9:19:98:d6:5f
  IF-ID-17: vetha263426 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full mac: 52:49:ce:84:bd:8a
  IF-ID-18: vetha6b06e0 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full mac: 06:3b:f7:d5:6a:35
  IF-ID-19: vethb425047 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full mac: 16:09:d5:97:ba:bf
  IF-ID-20: vethb47515e state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full mac: 9a:bf:01:37:4c:97
  IF-ID-21: vethc81cd6a state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full mac: 66:cd:be:ba:0b:73
  IF-ID-22: vethca2c23c state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full mac: 0a:29:34:b8:9f:3d
  IF-ID-23: vethd24261f state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full mac: 6e:1a:9c:6d:23:f9
  IF-ID-24: vethdec527a state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full mac: e6:29:c4:6b:bd:4d
  IF-ID-25: vethe145a66 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full mac: 06:49:63:37:16:f3
  IF-ID-26: vethe777ff7 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full mac: a6:8b:93:b9:6f:24
  IF-ID-27: vethef162e6 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full mac: 8a:a0:f6:e4:58:32
  IF-ID-28: vethfbd37fc state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full mac: b6:83:ee:f6:c4:09
  IF-ID-29: vethfed61f6 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full mac: 16:a9:e0:2f:42:e6

